# Lucene queryparser with “\” and trailing wildcard in query criteria

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm writing some queries using Apache Lucene Query Parser Syntax, however some of my queries include Windows directories with trailing wildcards, `C:\Intel\Logs\*`.

```
filter:
- query:
   query_string:
      query: "(event_id:1) AND (event_data.Image:C:\Intel\Logs\*)"
```

Running this query should do the following:

1. Whenever event_id = 1 and event_data.Image = C:\Intel\Logs\anything.exe is generated, the query will produce a hit.

Of course this does not work due to a syntax error:

> found unknown escape character 'I'

The specific escape character is in `event_data.Image:`. I'm running out of ideas on how to properly format my query so that I can successfully execute the query logic above.